# Python - None returned by using cursor.fetchone()

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Internet searches have told me to use cursor.fetchone() as a way to get a particular row from an SQL database in python. But when I use it, I get a None. I'm pretty sure there is stuff in there, so I'm confused about why this is happening.
Here is some code

```
db = sqlite3.connect('dataset.db')
curs = db.cursor()
curs.execute("CREATE TABLE data(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, dataObj REAL)")

def addData(info):
    curs.execute('''INSERT INTO data(dataObj) VALUES (?)''', (info, ))

def write(dataHolder): #to put the row vals into the table
    for x in range(0, len(dataHolder)):
        addData(dataHolder[x])
    db.commit()

def read(x):
    sqlQuery = "SELECT dataObj FROM data WHERE id = ?"
    result = curs.execute(sqlQuery, (x, )).fetchone()  #should return row from data table
    print result  #returns None

dataHolder = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5]
write(dataHolder)
for x in range(0, len(dataHolder)):
    read(dataHolder[x + 1])
```

I'm using this so that I can save work on my program and then resume it when I restart it. I feel like I'm doing something dumb, so sorry if it's something easy.

Comment: There is no `dataThing` column in the table `data`. Are you sure you get `None` rather than an error?

Comment: I meant dataObj, I fixed it now, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare - I did, but I haven't included how I did that in the code shown above

Comment: You need to give us an actual minimal reproduction of code that you think should print something, but prints nothing. As you've written the code, it makes perfect sense that it prints `None`. Voting to close until you give us something that actually needs explaining.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare, my bad, you're right, I entered how I put data into the table, in the above code.

Comment: Ah, it looks like you didn't `commit`. Add `db.commit()` after insertion. (In fact change should be visible to the connection which makes the change even without `commit`, but if you `SELECT` from another connection, which is probably what you are doing, you will not see the change.)

Comment: I would also mention that depending on the `id` to be anything in particular seems like a poor choice. I'd just drop the `WHERE` clause from the `SELECT` statement, if I were you.

Comment: @gill Okay so I did the commit part, but it still returns None :(

Comment: Please post your original code (but keep it to the bare essentials), so we can debug the real thing.

Comment: @gill I edited the code for the bare essentials. Hope it's helpful!

Comment: it looks like you are querying `WHERE id = 0.1` I don't think that should return anything. Also, your loop is wrong. Your index goes to far (why the `+1` btw?)

Comment: also, your code can't run. this line `for y in dataHolder[x]` looks out of place. please have a look at http://sscce.org/

Comment: This can't be the real code. `write` has a syntax error. `info` in `addData` is undefined, and so is `sql` in `read`.

Comment: @njzk2 Actually wouldn't I be querying WHERE id = 0.1 since it's a range?

Comment: @gill Yeah, I'm really dumb, I wrote it wrong in the stack overflow editor, but I fixed those points and the problem still remains. Sorry, again

Comment: @lightcreate I don't get your last comment. `WHERE id = 0.1` can't return anything, because `id` is an Integer.

Answer (score 1):

You probably know this, but if you have `INTEGER PRIMARY KEY` in your table creation statement, then that column will have integer values starting from 1 and automatically incrementing (unless you override it with an explicit value) whenever you insert a row. So your table looks like this:

```
id |  dataObj
---+---------
1  |  0.1
2  |  0.2
3  |  0.3
4  |  0.4
5  |  0.5
```

So this is wrong:

```
for x in range(0, len(dataHolder)):
    read(dataHolder[x + 1])
```

As you iterate, `x` takes the value of `0`, `1`, `2`, `3` and `4`. And `dataHolder[x + 1]`, the argument passed to `read()`, will be `0.2`, `0.3`, `0.4`, `0.5` for the first 4 iterations (the 5th is `IndexError`). This means your SELECT statement will be selecting for `id = 0.1`, etc. And you have no such id.

It should be

```
for x in range(len(dataHolder)):  # btw, you don't need 0
    read(x + 1)
```

(Even if you don't use a debugger, errors like this can be easily detected by inserting a few `print` into your code. E.g. if you had `print(x)` in `read`, you'd know that the id isn't what you think it is.)

Comment: @lightcreate I tested with the code your posted and it worked. Is your real code still different from what you posted?

Comment: @lightcreate Also, try `SELECT * FROM data` and see what the table does contain. It should be what I described in the answer, given your INSERT code.